# PHP: file() each character is preceded by "\0"

Tags: php, file, ini, autohotkey

I have an INI file that has been created by an AutoHotKey program written by another member of a team I am working on. I am trying to read the file into PHP as an array. I am using the built in `file()` function. When I read in the file and then display it using `var_dump($file)` (`$file` is the name of the array the file is being read into) each character is preceded by a "\0"(which is a null character). Each  Has anyone seen this happen before? I could just remove all the null characters after I read in the file, but I would prefer to find a solution.

When I open the ini file in text editors it opens just fine. I also read in using the `file()` function the desktop.ini file created by Windows and it read in as expected, the characters were not preceded by "\0"

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/04/15-top-php-coding-tutorials-tips-and.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the encoding of the file.  Some (most) unicode encodings require 2 bytes per character.  This means that each single byte character is prefixed with a \0.  The file is still perfectly valid, but if you try to read it with a windows-1252 type single byte encoding it will look odd.  You can try feeding it through [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) and see if that clears it up.  UTF 8 is a potential multibyte encoding from 1 to 4 bytes (with a minimum of 1).
Your text editor automatically figure this out and opens it as unicode which is why it looks fine there.

Note: because it uses a 2 byte encoding, it is specifically not utf-8, it may be utf-16, but the UTF-8 functions may be able to parse it.

Comment: The utf8_decode function does not seam to be able to parse it. It appears the encoding is a 16-bit Unicode format. Do you know of a PHP function that would be able to parse this?

Comment: `$fixed = mb_convert_encoding($broken, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');` may do it, if it is really UTF-16.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the mb string functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 0):

have you opened the file in a HEX Editor? There are probably hidden characters in your file...

Comment: Yes I have and it appears that every other character is a null character. I can not change how the program that generates the ini files encodes text but it appears it is using a 16-bit Unicode format. Is there a way to convert this in the PHP so that the file can be properly displayed?